# How to compute the beta-functions given the euclidean action for two scalar fields?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, path-integral

Given the Euclidean action for two scalar fields in $d$ dimensions:
\begin{equation}
S_E = \int d^dx\frac{1}{2}((\nabla\phi_1)^2 + \nabla\phi_2)^2) + \frac{\lambda}{4!}(\phi^4_1 + \phi^4_2) + \frac{2\kappa}{4!}\phi_1^2\phi_2^2
\end{equation}

with two couplings $\lambda$ and $\kappa$. I need to compute the $\beta$ functions for $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ to one-loop order, with $d=4$.

I know how to compute a $\beta$ function for an Euclidian action with one scalar field, but I don't know how to change the procedure when I am dealing with two fields instead of one.

For one scalar field I would start from the definition from the $\beta$ function $\beta(\tilde{\lambda})$ = $\mu\frac{\partial\tilde{\lambda}}{\partial\mu}$, where $\tilde{\lambda} = \mu^{d-4}\lambda(\mu)$. Then I find this result for the coupling $\lambda$, $\beta$ = $\frac{3}{16\pi^2}\frac{\mu^4}{(\mu^2 + \frac{\kappa^2}{36})^2}\lambda(\mu)^2 + \mathbb{o(\lambda^3)}$, and I think is correct but I don't know how it changes for two scalar fields.